# How to send &euro; or € sign in email subject using phpMailer class

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending email using PHPMailer.

I want to send price in subject, e.g "Bid of Price 460 € has been placed".

I used € and € in subject but it doesn't display properly. It shows `&euro` instead incase of `&euro;`

What should I use to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsMail();
$body = $mailBody;
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;"; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail -> AddAddress( $email, '' );  

$mail -> SetFrom( 'support@abc.com', 'Support Fretbay.com');
$mail -> Subject = 'Bid of Price 460 € has been placed';
$mail -> AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
$mail -> MsgHTML($body);
$mail -> Send();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subjects can't contain html entities, so `&euro;` won't work. You have to use charset that contains euro symbol, and set `$mail->CharSet` property. And sure, your `€` char must use this charset too:

```
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = 'Bid of Price 460 € has been placed';
```

Answer (score 1):

Its important that the euro sign is UTF-8 to be displayed correctly.

A simple solution is to use mb_encode_mimeheader, to be 100% sure.

```
$subject = "Here is &euro;500!";
$subject = str_replace('&euro;', mb_encode_mimeheader('€', 'UTF-8'), $subject);
```

Works well with PHPMailer and PEAR::Mail